# Grails service fails working with Optional class

Tags: java, grails, model-view-controller, groovy, option-type

I've tried to use Optionals in grails service, but whenever I do, I get
    HTTP Status 500 - Error applying layout : main
and a bunch of stack traces, which looks to me like nothing but framework gizmos. But when I try the same code in controller, it works ok. Here's a simplified example:

```
class SomeService {

   Optional<Object> testOptional() {
        return Optional.empty()
    }

}

class SomeController {

  //...//

  // this one works
  def a() {
     render Optional.empty()
  }

  // this does not
  def b() {
    render someService.testOptional()
  }

}
```

Apart from that, other methods in this service works ok.

Any Ideas?

P.S. [here's the full error](http://pastie.org/9971823)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're having some transaction done when getting over the service code.

Try to add `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` for your service/controller method and see what happends.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Could you explain what was the problem?

Comment: When your code passes between the controller layer to the service layer, there is an automated `commit` opertation to the DB by the embedded JPA on Grails. As I can see it from here, it tried to save something which wasn't clear enough.